# How do I authenticate to the GoodData API?

Tags: api, authentication, gooddata

I am trying to authenticate / login with the GoodData API but I am having trouble. On the GoodData API documentation site (docs.gooddata.apiary.io) it says to POST to:

URL:

> https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login

Headers:

> ```
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> ```

JSON Body:

> {"postUserLogin":{"login":"user@company.com","password":"YourPassword","remember":1}}

I get the response "Private API, please provide private hash." Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The updated GoodData API documentation and API console is located at https://developer.gooddata.com/api

The login URL for this call is actually https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login

Using the same payload (your credentials instead of sample) you will be able to login and get the SST Token that is returned back in SetCookie header.

Please remember the process to login is:

1. POST your credentials to the login resource as mentioned here
2. SST Token is returned back in SetCookie header
3. GET the token resource with SST Token in your header to receive TT Token
4. Use the TT Token in your API calls header: -cookie

Also, please remember that TT Token has limited validity. Once you received 401 Unauthorized Response, you need to GET new TT Token in following resource with SST Token specified in call header.

Answer (score 3):

regarding the GoodData Apiary I have example in CURL

1st Step - POST to https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login:

```
jirka@x230:~$ curl --include --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data-binary "{\"postUserLogin\":{\"login\":\"jiri.simon@gooddata.com\",\"password\":\"`cat my_pass.txt`\",\"remember\":1}}" "https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login" 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-GDC-REQUEST: 7AEoVKre3lTF8sUV 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthTT=; path=/gdc; expires=Sat, 07-Sep-2013 22:16:26 GMT; secure; HttpOnly 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthSST=jcftYGCC3u6pkNRK; path=/gdc/account; expires=Wed, 23-Oct-2013 22:16:26 GMT; secure; HttpOnly 
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
P3P: CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT' 
X-GDC-REQUEST-TIME: 69 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 143 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 22:16:26 GMT 
X-Varnish: 2109577795 
Age: 0 
Via: 1.1 varnish 
Connection: keep-alive

{"userLogin":{"profile":"/gdc/account/profile/254c399a3f5131b7026313d4f8761410","state":"/gdc/account/login/254c399a3f5131b7026313d4f8761410"}}
```

2nd step is to get GDCAuthTT using SST from the response from 1st step:

```
jirka@x230:~$ curl --include --header "Cookie: $Version=0; GDCAuthSST=jcftYGCC3u6pkNRK; $Path=/gdc/account" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/tokenHTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-GDC-REQUEST: GqPnYyk3pKAW5eju 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthTT=h3CUUg72U2SLhL7Tghj_TVnba6byjgj3L78aJkSFuoji_0DiqXGRYY7C1zWDa-2yIa0Aj3-MuVlWPdNSx7N7CDzM7w21Fl6OaMjuF-98bV6cRx34HW-ql6IGt6ufWo_U5fQa2QqU6b-F0MsGE6orDC6ZMt2anJQdATNYsHfELiB7ImwiOiIwIiwidSI6IjE3Mzk4NyIsImsiOiJiZWQyZWU1ZS05YzYxLTRhNWMtOWJlNi05ZTAxZDQ4NjI5NmEiLCJ1aWQiOiIyNTRjMzk5YTNmNTEzMWI3MDI2MzEzZDRmODc2MTQxMCIsInYiOjEzODExODQ4MTZ9; path=/gdc; secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
P3P: CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT' 
X-GDC-TIMESTAMP: 600 
X-GDC-REQUEST-TIME: 20 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 2 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 22:16:56 GMT 
X-Varnish: 1661889108 
Age: 0 
Via: 1.1 varnish 
Connection: keep-alive
```

And then you can use all other calls using your GDCAuthTT, but this GDCAuthTT has validity only 10 minutes and after 10 minutes you'll get 401 and you have to call previous command again for new GDCAuthTT

Answer (score 2):

GoodData authentication is also implemented in the following libraries:

- Perl - http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::GoodData
- Java - https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-http-client

Answer (score 2):

or you can use python and code should look like following

```
jirka@x230:~$ python 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> from urllib2 import Request, urlopen 
>>> from json import dumps 
>>> values = dumps({"postUserLogin":{"login":"jiri.simon@gooddata.com","password":"secredpassword","remember":1}}) 
>>> headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"} 
>>> request = Request("https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/login", data=values, headers=headers) 
>>> response_body = urlopen(request) 
>>> print response_body.read() 
{"userLogin":{"profile":"/gdc/account/profile/254c399a3f5131b7026313d4f8761410","state":"/gdc/account/login/254c399a3f5131b7026313d4f8761410"}} 
>>> print response_body.info() 
X-GDC-REQUEST: FnETpOmoAPELJoS1 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthTT=; path=/gdc; expires=Wed, 08-Jan-2014 20:07:00 GMT; secure; HttpOnly 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthSST=QubuMlx3byz6lta1; path=/gdc/account; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2014 20:07:00 GMT; secure; HttpOnly 
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
P3P: CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT' 
X-GDC-LOG-HEADER: 
X-GDC-REQUEST-TIME: 53 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 143 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 20:07:00 GMT 
X-Varnish: 1076092393 
Age: 0 
Via: 1.1 varnish 
Connection: close

>>> headers = {"Cookie": "$Version=0; GDCAuthSST=QubuMlx3byz6lta1; $Path=/gdc/account", "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"} 
>>> request = Request("https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/token", headers=headers) 
>>> response_body = urlopen(request) 
>>> print response_body.read() 
{} 
>>> print response_body.info() 
X-GDC-REQUEST: IyuefQK4mMIm4Vqr 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: GDCAuthTT=VL_Bum5jjd8cEtFUa6XF5tfVmmiFDn7ZyB6a95kEuhzlQw-D67RIL_8u1E9e_z3yDx2bgHrsVNwX6zY1XRzsVpgtvC7HY2JBWiTtq63_Y-XxQwN9cO9RJO6GwM8WnshREwXXgzUk0vr9U4Gg-a4FnEs5NR4ySWOW1bhjnFSJFG17ImwiOiIwIiwidSI6IjE3Mzk4NyIsImsiOiIxYTZiNzc4ZC0yNDkyLTQ2OWEtODliYy1lNWQ1OWU1ODAyNDUiLCJ1aWQiOiIyNTRjMzk5YTNmNTEzMWI3MDI2MzEzZDRmODc2MTQxMCIsInYiOjEzOTE4MDQzMjV9; path=/gdc; secure; HttpOnly 
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
P3P: CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT' 
X-GDC-TIMESTAMP: 600 
X-GDC-LOG-HEADER: 
X-GDC-REQUEST-TIME: 30 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 2 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 20:08:45 GMT 
X-Varnish: 1076094531 
Age: 0 
Via: 1.1 varnish 
Connection: close
```